# It's possible to use a collection in WHERE clausule and condition IN?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

It's possible to do something like the following?

```
create or replace TYPE "TypeKeys" IS TABLE OF INTEGER;
/
Declare
    Keys TypeKeys;
    personT PERSON%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    Keys := TypeKeys();
    Keys.EXTEND(2);
    Keys(1) := 14;
    Keys(2) := 21;

    SELECT * INTO personT FROM PERSON WHERE ID IN (Keys);
END;
/
```

I need to find rows by multiple id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `member of`:

```
SELECT * INTO personT FROM PERSON WHERE ID MEMBER OF Keys;
```

or a table collection expression:

```
 SELECT * INTO personT FROM PERSON WHERE ID IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(Keys));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ff5ecc0b9aac70862efe168ad80910c)

Of course, as you're selecting into a single record you'll get an error if there isn't exactly one matching row, however many key values you include in the collection.

Comment: for my case it was more convenient to use the first option
Thanks a lot!